# ATMega328: How to select alternate function on a pin

Tags: atmega

This might be an easy question, but I couldn't find an answer to it in the Alternate Port Functions section of the ATMega328 datasheet (page 80)

Take pin PB3 as an example. As well as having a use as a GPIO pin, it is also wired to MOSI, OC2A, and PCINT3. How do you select which signal is wired to PB3?

Specifically, if I wanted to use PB3 as a GPIO pin, but I was using timer2 for some other function (which would have a side effect of setting and/or clearing OC2A), will the two signals interfere, and how would I avoid that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specific to timer/counter control register A, **register TCCR2A bits 7:6 COM2A1:0** control whether or not the internal **OC2A** signal overrides the normal PORTB3 pin behavior. See datasheet section 17.11.1 TCCR2A – Timer/Counter Control Register A - found by searching within the datasheet for OC2A.

The section you referenced **13.3 Alternate Port Functions** gives a generic description of how all of the alternate port functions are worked out, but only goes as far as the override signal names. See table 13-5 for Overriding Signals for Alternate Functions in PB3..PB0. They give a bunch of Boolean expressions for each of the overrides -- PVOE is "Port Value Override Enable" and PVOV is "Port Value Override Value" as per the earlier diagram 13-5 Alternate Port Functions. To find out which actual bitfield in which register controls each alternate pin function, you have to search the signal name within the datasheet.